# R - Can not merge a CSV, for some reason

Tags: r, csv, statistics

```
> imqd = read.csv("csv/quest/IMQ.csv")
> demod = read.csv("csv/DEMO.csv")
> mcqd = read.csv("csv/quest/MCQ.csv")
> 
> length(demod)
[1] 145
> length(demod[[1]])
[1] 9965
> length(mcqd)
[1] 168
> length(mcqd[[1]])
[1] 9493
> length(imqd)
[1] 5
> length(imqd[[1]])
[1] 9965
> 
> mydata = merge(imqd, demod)
> length(mydata)
[1] 148
> length(mydata[[1]])
[1] 9965
```

So far, so good. But, if I try to merge `mcqd` with anything, I lose most of my rows, even though the data looks good to me.

```
> intersect(intersect(names(imqd), names(mcqd)), names(demod))
[1] "X"    "seqn"

> finaldata = merge(mydata, mcqd)
> length(finaldata)
[1] 314
> length(finaldata[[1]])
[1] 18
```

Why are there only 18 rows now?

If you want to play along at home, you can [get the csv files here](https://github.com/skyl/NHANES-opensource/tree/master/1999-2000/csv).

Comment: I think maybe `merge` doesn't mean what you think it means. It does an inner join on all matching columns by default. Anything not matched is dropped, just like in sql. You might want to investigate the `by` and `all` arguments.

Comment: all three files have two columns almost completely in common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`merge` is trying to return only those rows which match on each of the common columns.
Looking at [MCQ.csv](https://raw.github.com/skyl/NHANES-opensource/master/1999-2000/csv/quest/MCQ.csv), we see that the 20th row starts off:

```
"19",20,2,NA,
```

`merge` will not use this row.  Both of the common columns, the first and the second columns, do not match for every file. The `pk` of the data to merge on is clearly `seqn`. So, we can simply use the `by` argument to `merge`:

```
> finaldata = merge(mydata, mcqd, by="seqn")
```

Comment: As I suspected, you just have to look very carefully at the values in the first/second columns. In particular, check out MCQ. The value 19 is skipped, which means it's off from the others for all the remaining values.

Comment: More to the point, the inclusion of the row numbers column when joining forced the issue.

Comment: Spot on, you can make an answer for me to accept, if you like; and, I'll delete this one.

Comment: Not necessary, just edit it into your question. I don't need more rep.

Comment: You probably want to use `read.csv(..., row.names=1)` to read the rownames properly (rather than into a column `X`). Merge may then work without specifying the key (although its probably not a bad idea to do so).